# Removing osx-gcc-installer

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm using MAC OS X 10.8.5. I'm getting this error that I have osx-gcc-installer installed and I need to install either CLT or Xcode 5.0.1. However, I already have downloaded and installed CLT and Xcode 5.0.1, and I'm not sure how I'm suppose to remove osx-gcc-installer.

Errors I get:

```
Warning: You seem to have osx-gcc-installer installed.
Homebrew doesn't support osx-gcc-installer. It causes many builds to fail and
is an unlicensed distribution of really old Xcode files.
Please install the CLT or Xcode 5.0.1.
```

Some of the solutions I've found from another posts:

```
If something doesn't work as expected, feel free to install Xcode over this installation.

Once installed, you can remove Xcode completely with the following:

sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools -mode=all
```

It says, I need to install Xcode over if there's problem with osx-gcc-installer, but I've already installed Xcode. In this case, should I uninstall and reinstall my Xcode?

Also, I ran the code they provided and uninstalled the devtools.

I really hope there's an easier and effective way to remove osx-gcc-installer.

Comment: did you managed to find any solution to your question?